# Solving for x in binary operations of a group

Tags: binary-operations

Given the equation, of a group A. Determine x in terms of j,k,l.

$$k∗x∗x = j∗l$$

Given that we know that its a group, we know that the binary operation has an identity, each element has an inverse and it is associative. 
We can add $k^{-1}$ to the left of each side by using an operation.
That is,

$$k^{-1} ∗ k ∗ x ∗ x = k^{-1} ∗ j ∗ l$$

We can use the associative property to show that

$$k^{-1} ∗ k ∗ x ∗ x = (k^{-1} ∗ k) ∗ (x ∗ x)$$

And since k^{-1} ∗ k = e (From the inverse property). We get,

$$e ∗ x ∗ x = k^{-1} ∗ j ∗ l$$

and since e ∗ x = x (From the identity property).
We get,

$$x ∗ x = k^{-1} ∗ j ∗ l$$

This is where I end up but I can't determine x in terms of j,k,l without having an inverse term alongside it.

Either I get

$$x = x^{-1} ∗ k^{-1} ∗ j ∗ l$$, or I get $$x = k^{-1} ∗ j ∗ l ∗ x^{-1}$$

Is it possible to determine x in terms of j,k,l for this example? And if so, where should I start/what have I done incorrectly?

Comment: You started perfectly, but now the equation $x^2=k^{-1}jl$ cannot be solved without some specific knowledge about the group (or, at least, about the product $k^{-1}jl$). There are examples with any number of solutions of this equation, from zero to infinity.